# Selenium webdriver c# for IE/Chrome browser is not responding quickly when trying to run all test methods in one go by login only once

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, coded-ui-tests, browser-automation

I am running [test method] using selenium web driver c#. Here I have to launch browser only once and then continue the

execution of rest of methods sequentially one by one.
For continuing the execution of all the methods, i have placed following code in test cleanup-

```
[TestCleanup]
        public void TestCleanUp()
        {

            BrowserWindow browserWindow = new BrowserWindow();
            browserWindow.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;
            Selenium.Driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
        }
```

But here my first methods runs well but to start 2nd ,3rd ...n methods it is losing the focus from browser hence for sometime Ie becomes not responding & which results in test fail.

In short i am not able to execute all my methods only launching browser once. I have maintained all the order for test methods. but When one [Test method] finishes its execution ...2nd is not started.

My browser is not closed for second test run but second test run is looks like not responding . But 10-15 minutes it starts my second test method on same existing browser.

Is there is solution for Selenium Web driver c#--IE & chrome browser ..always keep focus on browser window instead of other??

Comment: It's quite similar to my issue. When I repeated my  tests on the same IE for several time, IE is getting slower and finally freezes. The root cause of my issue is "XPath" locator doesn't work well on IE. I solved it by changing all locators to CssSelector.

Comment: I have Used axes XPath like \\[contains(text(),'Home')]...And for seperate login of all test it works fast and also gives good results.                             When we attempt to run all test together like launch browser only once --in that case 1 st method execution completes its execution very fast and then updates results in Test Explorer ..so for that time it looses focus from IE and when selenium ie driver start to trigger next methods it can not kick off execution quicky ..it becomes slow ...

Comment: I feel your issue is as same as mine. Could you change locators from XPath to CssSelector? I think it will help.

Comment: For all methods u mean to say... It will take a lot of time from changing xpath to css selector ......i can change it for some methods and try ..but r u sure css selecor will work ...our script has mode code which xpath in order to run on any environment ...if i changed it to css selector then its scopr will be restricted to only one environment isn;t it??

Comment: Not, not all locators. Just try to change them as much as you can; then run the test to confirm if it help or not.

Comment: Ok i see , and update you on the results ..

Comment: Changing Xpath to css selector also taking time to start the second method execution..........I am curious about why it is loosing focus from browser when one method finishes it execution ..and try to run second methods in that case ie driver can not kick off second test method quickly ...Focus should be always be on browser ...

Comment: My Problem is like....
When [TestMethod] A { },
[TestMethod] B { },
[TestMethod] C { }

When A finishes its execution in 20 secconds then driver or engine update results in test explorer hence browser focus got lost...
But here i am not closing browser here so driver try to run second method B but it is taking 4-5 minuts for its completition
here for second method the time should be less ..as i am avoiding login ..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reuse a browser window then you need to follow a specific pattern to do it consistent and succesfull.

First initialize the browser window in the testinitialize method. since this is before the initialization of the playback engine, initialize it yourself as follows:

```
[ClassInitialize]
public static void initializeTest(TestContext context)
{
     Playback.Initialize();
     var _bw = BrowserWindow.Launch(new Uri("http://www.bing.com"));
     proc = _bw.Process;
    _bw.CloseOnPlaybackCleanup = false;
}
```

next in every test method you can then reuse the windows as follows:

```
[TestMethod]
public void CodedUITestMethodFirstTest()
{
    BrowserWindow _bw = BrowserWindow.FromProcess(proc);
   _bw.NavigateToUrl(new Uri("http://www.bing.com"));
   //do your stuff here
}
```

Unfortunately reuse of the browser window in playback on chrome or firefox is not supported. this is a documented shortcoming of the selenium bridge implementation:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/10/30/introducing-cross-browser-testing-with-coded-ui-tests/